# Duende Identity server encrypted email

Tags: asp.net-core, duende-identity-server

*Which version of Duende IdentityServer are you using?*

Duende Identity Server v6

*Which version of .NET are you using?*

.NET Core 6

*Describe the situation*

We store the email address encrypted via symmetric key algorithm (i.e. `RijndaelSimple`). The encrypted email has lower and upper case letters, numbers and special characters (i.e. =,+,/). If we try to store the encrypted email in the `AspNetUser` table, the normalized email column may produce the same result. Hence, it may result in issues. How can we manage this situation in the best way?

*Expected behavior*

Be able to manage encrypted email without the complexities coming from normalized email.

*Additional context*

Storing email in an encrypted format is important for us for security purposes.

Comment: [How about adding timestamp in the email address ?](https://codeshare.io/QnVBRL)